# Generic type for something like Lodash sumby

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How would you type a function that effectively does what [lodash.sumby](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sumBy) does with keys? The [DefinitelyTyped types for it](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/d5bb4de24757f46ed52865e92c206b4c95d4714a/types/lodash/common/math.d.ts#L391) are loose and do not specify that the string argument needs to be a key of the type of the collection.

The following seems to get close, but it doesn't specify that the type of `T[key]` is a number

```js
function sumByKey<T>(list: T[], key: keyof T) {
  return list.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item[key], 0);
}
```

so it has the error

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'T[keyof T]'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a generic type parameter `T` for the array elements, I would use the generic to describe the key.

We don't care about all of the details of the list elements.  All that we need to know is that each element in `list` is an object (including array) which has a property `T` whose value is a `number`.

We must make sure that:

- the `key` is `T`
- `T extends PropertyKey`
- `list` is an `Array`
- the elements of `list` are type `{ [K in T]: number }` aka `Record<T, number>`

```
function sumByKey<T extends PropertyKey>(list: { [K in T]: number }[], key: T) {
  return list.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item[key], 0);
}
```

Now the function has no errors because `item[key]` must be `number`.

---

There is a bit of a limitation when it comes to writing your list inline.

This is fine:

```
const data = [{x: 30, a: 20}, {x: 50, b: 20}];
const sum = sumByKey(data, 'x');
```

But this gives an error:

```
const sum = sumByKey([{x: 30, a: 20}, {x: 50, b: 20}], 'x');
```

> Type '{ x: number; a: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ x: number; }'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'a' does not exist in type '{ x: number; }'

If you want to avoid this error, you can change your definition of `list` so that it has a property `T: number` *and also* any amount of other unknown properties.

```
function sumByKey<T extends PropertyKey>(
    list: ({ [K in T]: number } & { [K in PropertyKey]?: unknown })[],
    key: T
) {
  return list.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item[key], 0);
}
```

Now both work without error.

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxAWwEIE8DSBTLAHgBVE8APKPMAE2UQAUAnOABzyalwID4AKALAAoRKMQAbGMigAuRHwDeiANo5EMJMQC6csOgBGHRAF9EAMkRLV6pMzYcu%20LDsTgA1mDgB3JMYCUyloANMJiiG4EcsTCfpahiEx4UCBMSJLSAHSJNCAQeHx8qGhB6lRosQC8PCjoiADUpXhoyhHOJQAMfgDcwsbCwhAI0og0AIZQo4gVKgrkcgDM7SWjcgBM7cYls3IArEuI%20msbWj1Cg2DDRVM1mNxYfGMTJQDk5M-d-WdDcOJ4GeJwADmhXQHyEAyGUBuABYAIzXIrYJx8ZTbRCLZZHTaWOaIPYlQ6IdbGYKIV7vU4Qi4-P4A4FFOHdIA)