# Typescript generic function with dynamic key

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to write a function that calculates the sum of an objects property in an array. And I want it to make as strict as possible.

Right now, I got this:

```
function sum<T>(arr: T[], key: keyof T) {
  return arr.reduce((curr, next) => curr + next[key], 0);
}
```

But there's an issue that `next[key]` is unknown. I would like somehow to specify that `T extends {[key]: number}`. And I would like to avoid using `as`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
function sum<T extends string>(arr: { [K in T]: number }[], key: T) {
  return arr.reduce((curr, next) => curr + next[key], 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67677787/8001865